# Does Matlab Coder has a issue to short a vector with ja variable?

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

I have a Problem in Matlab Coder. So, Im trying to short a vector with a variable.

```
[aa,a] = min(array(:));
idx=single(a(1,1));
b= c(1:idx,1);
```

Error:
Could not determine the size of this expression.

Index is a single Variable. 
I guess... Matlab has a problem with this and i have to write a workaround? Because if I type '20'.... everything is fine, -> Code Generate...

Thank you guys for you help!

Comment: Could you give an example `array` and `c`? I wasn't able to reproduce the error with my test data. What Matlab version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

okay more details:

array is single 100x1 ;
aa is so -> single 1x1 ;
a -> double 1x1 ;

idx -> Single 1x1 ;

c is single 100x1 ;

Matlab version : 2015b 64bit